Close hole in object
I have this object that has a rectangular hole in it:

I would like to close the hole.
At first I thought I can just add a face at the top, add a face at the bottom and remove the faces that make up the inner wall of the hole. But the faces of the hole extend to outside of the hole, so I can't remove them:

My next idea was to put a box in there (the hole is perfectly box-shaped) and boolean it into the object. Unfortunately my Blender skills are insufficient to create a box with its corners snapping to the corner vertices of the hole.


Hello could you please share your file?

If that second image with the red arrows shows what happened when you tried to fill the top surface, you seem to have selected one edge from the top and one from the bottom of the object before trying to fill it! You should be able to do it exactly as you suggested. As @moonboots says please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

The red arrows just show where the faces extend outside the hole, they're before any changes. I have added the file.

I found a way. It's a bit clunky and maybe someone more knowledgeable will add a better method.
Luckily some sides of the hole consist of whole :) faces. So I used those to extrude them into a box of the correct size.

First I had to extract the faces that I wanted to extrude. I tried Mesh > Separate > Selection but that removes them from the original object. So instead, I duplicated the object. There is no "duplicate" operation in the Outliner, so I used Copy followed by Paste.
I then selected the duplicate, entered Edit Mode, selected the faces on one side of the hole, did Select > Invert and hit Del > Faces to delete the rest of the object.



(The new object shown in Object Mode.)

With the faces still selected I activated the Extrude Region tool. At the same time I made sure that snapping is enabled and set to Snap To: Vertex.



I could now drag the yellow "+" circle onto a vertex opposite the faces, where it would snap, giving me a box of exactly the right dimensions.
After exiting Edit Mode I did a boolean union between both objects by using the new Boolean Modifier.
Finally I deleted the box object, leaving me with the "repaired" object.


I assume that object wasn't originally made in Blender? Before you started you should have used Mesh > Clean Up > Limited Dissolve in Edit mode to get rid of most of those spurious edges, however filling the top and bottom faces works fine without doing that.  If you want to remove all 4 inner faces, connect the two bottom vertices on the right hand side with 'J' and then you can select all the faces and delete them.

@JohnEason Ooh, that Limited Dissolve is nice. It was made in SketchUp and I imported it as an .stl into Blender.

Yep. It can make a big difference!
